# How to use dictionary in c# to compare two lists

Tags: c#, dictionary

Currently, I have implemented two lists with a double for loop to find matches between the two lists so I can join on them.

I have a list A which contains an ID and some other columns. I have a list B which contains an ID and some other columns. I have currently implemented a for loop within a for loop in order to make the comparisons for all the IDs so that I can find the ones that match and then return the joined results. I know want to understand how to implement a dictionary in this case as that will be more efficient to fix this problem.

```
public IEnumerable<Details> GetDetails(string ID)
{
  // there are two lists defined up here 
  for (var item in listA)
  {
    for (var item2 in listB)
    {
       if (item.ID == item2.ID)
       {
          item.Name = item2.name;
       }
    }
  }
    return results;
   }
```

Instead of having this double for loop, which is very inefficient. I want to learn how to implement a dictionary to fix this problem.

Comment: Why does your method take `ID` but never use it?

Comment: What is `results`? The contained or not contained? `var unContained = listA.Where(x => !listB.Contains(x));` Also is ID the Key or the Value? Are you trying to match on Key or Value or both?

Comment: Can you post a complete example with your an example input dataset and desired output?

Comment: The ID is taken for some other processes that take place earlier in the method. ID would be the key and I only want to match on key.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary would use the ids as keys (or indexes) so

```
Dictionary<string, object> myListA = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, object> myListB = new Dictionary<string, object>();

public object GetDetails(string ID)
{
    object a = myListA[ID];
    object b = myListB[ID];

    // combine them here how you want
    // object c = a + b;

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using linq to achieve your actual requirement? Something like:

```
public IEnumerable<A> GetDetails(int ID)
{
   var listA = new List<A>
   {
      new A(){ ID = 1, Name = 2 },
      new A(){ ID = 3, Name = 4 },
      new A(){ ID = 5, Name = 6 },
   };

   var listB = new List<B>
   {
       new B(){ X = 1, name = 0 },
       new B(){ X = 3, name = 1 }
   };

   return listA.Join(listB, k => k.ID, k => k.ID, (item, item2) =>
   {
       item.Name = item2.name;
       return item;
   }).Where(w => w.ID == ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the common `ID`s in the two lists, you can achieve that like this:

`var commonIds = listA.Select(o => o.ID).Intersect(listB.Select(o => o.ID));`

Comment: I want to be able to join the information from one list to the other if there are common IDs. I do not just want to know which IDs are common. So I think this will not work?